# Re-size image based on small medium large radio button selection: Is it possible through CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an employee extension list table with employee name and employees thumb-nail image next to it.
I have a requirement to provide the user with small medium large radio button (or drop down) options and display the employee image accordingly. I was wondering if this can be done using CSS? Or can I create a CSS class in java script based on the radio button selection? I tried to do it through java script but it only works on my first row. rest of the rows are unchanged. Here is a glimpse of my code.

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(){

alert(document.getElementById("lastName").getAttribute("style"));

var imgSize = document.getElementById("lastName").getAttribute("style");


if(document.getElementById('ImgSizeSmall').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('lastName').setAttribute("style", "width:75px;" );
} else if(document.getElementById('ImgSizeMedium').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('lastName').setAttribute("style", "width:100px;" );
}  else if(document.getElementById('ImgSizeLarge').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('lastName').setAttribute("style", "width:150px;" );
}
</Script>

<Div style="width:385px;height: 950px; float:left; background-color:#A5B3D8;">
    <p align="left">

    <p align="left"><b>Image Size:</b><br>
        <input id="ImgSizeSmall" type="radio" name="ImgSize" value="small" checked="checked" onclick="changeClass()">  <b><i>Small</i></b>
        <input id="ImgSizeMedium" type="radio" name="ImgSize" value="medium"> <b><i>Medium</i></b>
        <input id="ImgSizeLarge" type="radio" name="ImgSize" value="large"> <b><i>Large</i></b>
    </p>

</DIV> 

<table id="table_firstname_lastname">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 208px;">First Name</th>
                <th style="width: 208px;">Last Name</th>
                <th style="width: 208px;">Phone Number</th>
                <th style="width: 275px;">Location</th>
                <th style="width: 208px;">Cell</th>
                <th style="width: 275px;">Team(s)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>             
            <tr>

                <td>first name</td>
                <td>last name 
                     <img  id="lastName" style="width: 75px;"  src="http://imagesource/image.jpg"  align="right"></a></td>

                <td>9999999999</td>
                <td>location 1</td>
                <td>8888888888</td>
                <td>team name</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks,
M

Comment: Please show the code of what you've tried so far. It would be the best to [create a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for such a question.

Comment: Are you swapping images, you have multiple files in these sizes, or are you actually re-sizing the image, changing the img tag's height and width?

Comment: My plan is to resize the image based on radio-button selection. Is having separate image files a better option?

Comment: @Nico O: Here is the link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p90643vL/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following java script class which solved my problem pretty well :)

```
function changeClass(){

var imgSize = document.getElementById("lastName").getAttribute("style");


var table;
if(document.getElementById('radio_firstname_lastname').checked == true) {

    table = document.getElementById('table_firstname_lastname');
} else {
    table = document.getElementById('table_lastname_firstname');
} 


if(document.getElementById('ImgSizeSmall').checked == true) {

    for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
        var x = table.rows[r].cells.item(0);
        x.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width="75px";

    }
} else if(document.getElementById('ImgSizeMedium').checked == true) {

    for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
        var x = table.rows[r].cells.item(0);
        x.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width="100px";

    }
}  else if(document.getElementById('ImgSizeLarge').checked == true) {

    for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
        var x = table.rows[r].cells.item(0);
        x.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.width="150px";

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I remembered an article from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/) that led to Fiddeling this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8trk87r/)

HTML:

```
<div> 
<input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
<input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
<input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
<img src="http://www.mycatspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/adopting-a-cat.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tab-1[type=radio]:checked ~ img 
{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

#tab-2[type=radio]:checked ~ img 
{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#tab-3[type=radio]:checked ~ img 
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

This might help you on your way..

Comment: This looks like a great solution. However as I am trying it on a table will it do for all the rows?

Comment: Can you please take a look my code above and suggest accordingly?